# Microsoft Bot send the response twice in Teams

Tags: botframework, bots, direct-line-botframework

I've used Microsoft bot framework SDKv4, and integrated to Teams channel. It is running well, but giving responses twice.

> [image]

**But, I didn't get the same behavior, while I tested it on Emulator and Web Chat in Azure Portal.**

However, I can see below issue, while I ping the bot in **web chat** and get a response.

> [image]

Further, I can also see, that its always '**sending**' as a status although I got a valid response, and the status later changes to "**Send Failed. Retry**"

> [image]

Is the issue related to my teams integration for getting message twice? and how, should I fix it!

Comment: The issue is occurring on different channels indicates the problem likely lies in your bot. To start, which SDK and version?

Comment: @StevenKanberg Microsoft Bot Framework SDKv4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made my bot working. It was the issue of MS authentication!

I had a call with MS support person and the root cause appeared to be only the MS authentication. Had to reset app secret and then re-deloyment.

Its weird that, although it was not getting authenticated primarily yet it was returning me the response. This, I still haven't got it!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using webhooks? If so, having multiple webhooks with same ID could be the reason  for double messages. Hope this helps

Comment: No.. I'm not using any webhooks!